# Cassandra is not showing a node up hours after restart

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am in the process of doing a rolling restart on a 4-node cluster running Cassandra 2.1.9. I stopped and started Cassandra on node 1 via "service cassandra stop/start", and noted nothing unusual in either system.log or cassandra.log. Doing a "nodetool status" from node 1 shows all four nodes up

```
user@node001=> nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.187.121  538.95 GB  256     ?       c99cf581-f4ae-4aa9-ab37-1a114ab2429b  rack1
UN  192.168.187.122  630.72 GB  256     ?       bfa07f47-7e37-42b4-9c0b-024b3c02e93f  rack1
UN  192.168.187.123  572.73 GB  256     ?       273df9f3-e496-4c65-a1f2-325ed288a992  rack1
UN  192.168.187.124  625.05 GB  256     ?       b8639cf1-5413-4ece-b882-2161bbb8a9c3  rack1
```

But doing the same command from any other nodes shows node 1 still down.

```
user@node002=> nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
DN  192.168.187.121  538.94 GB  256     ?       c99cf581-f4ae-4aa9-ab37-1a114ab2429b  rack1
UN  192.168.187.122  630.72 GB  256     ?       bfa07f47-7e37-42b4-9c0b-024b3c02e93f  rack1
UN  192.168.187.123  572.73 GB  256     ?       273df9f3-e496-4c65-a1f2-325ed288a992  rack1
UN  192.168.187.124  625.04 GB  256     ?       b8639cf1-5413-4ece-b882-2161bbb8a9c3  rack1
```

"nodetool compactionstats" shows no pending tasks, and "nodetool netstats" shows nothing unusual. It's been over 12 hours and these inconsistencies persist. Another example is when I do a "nodetool gossipinfo" on the restarted node, which shows its status as normal:

```
user@node001=> nodetool -u gossipinfo
/192.168.187.121
  generation:1574364410
  heartbeat:209150
  NET_VERSION:8
  RACK:rack1
  STATUS:NORMAL,-104847506331695918
  RELEASE_VERSION:2.1.9
  SEVERITY:0.0
  LOAD:5.78684155614E11
  HOST_ID:c99cf581-f4ae-4aa9-ab37-1a114ab2429b
  SCHEMA:fd2dcb4b-ca62-30df-b8f2-d3fd774f2801
  DC:datacenter1
  RPC_ADDRESS:192.168.185.121
```

Versus another node, which shows node001's status as "shutdown":

```
user@node002=> nodetool gossipinfo
/192.168.187.121
  generation:1491825076
  heartbeat:2147483647
  STATUS:shutdown,true
  RACK:rack1
  NET_VERSION:8
  LOAD:5.78679987693E11
  RELEASE_VERSION:2.1.9
  DC:datacenter1
  SCHEMA:fd2dcb4b-ca62-30df-b8f2-d3fd774f2801
  HOST_ID:c99cf581-f4ae-4aa9-ab37-1a114ab2429b
  RPC_ADDRESS:192.168.185.121
  SEVERITY:0.0
```

Is there something I can do to remedy this current situation - so that I can continue with the rolling restart?

Comment: Is the nodetool command you have, above, running from the "down" node (i.e. X.X.187.121)? If not, can you ensure you can run nodetool commands from that host. Can you log into that node via cqlsh? Check disk space? Not sure you can have cassandra spool debug logs. Sometimes applying commit logs takes time, but shouldn't take hours...

Comment: The nodetool command above was run from a different node. If I run it from the "down" node, that Status/State of all 4 nodes is "UN".

Comment: As a follow-up, is the only valid cluster status that which is returned from the most recently restarted node? I'm worried about proceeding with the rolling restart with the other three nodes (out of four) showing the first node still down (DN). The restarted node shows all four nodes up (UN).

Comment: You are right: if you restart another node when the first one `x.x.x.121` is considered as Down may cause errors, but this will depend on the replication factor and consistency level used (for instance, RF of 4 and consistency level of ONE won't be affected, while a lower RF or higher consistency will cause issues for sure). Are there any errors in the `cassandra/systems.log` file? In the past, I've solved a similar situation restarting the node that was considered as `DOWN` (x.121). Finally, it will be better that you run `nodetool drain` before restarting the service.

Comment: It still bothers me that the IP address in nodetool status is 192.168.187.121 and the rpc_address is different 192.168.185.121. Assuming this is by design.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ultimately ended up doing to get the "bad" node back into the cluster and to complete the rolling restart:

**Perform a complete shutdown**

```
nodetool disablethrift
nodetool disablebinary
sleep 5
nodetool disablegossip
nodetool drain
sleep 10
/sbin/service cassandra restart
```

**Monitor for return of the node**

```
until echo "SELECT * FROM system.peers LIMIT 1;" | cqlsh `hostname` > /dev/null 2>&1; do echo "Node is still DOWN"; sleep 10; done && echo "Node is now UP"
```

**Remove the restarted node from the Cluster**

From a different node in the cluster, perform the following command:

```
nodetool removenode <host-id>
```

**Perform a second complete shutdown**

```
nodetool disablethrift
nodetool disablebinary
sleep 5
nodetool disablegossip
nodetool drain
sleep 10
/sbin/service cassandra restart
```

**Monitor for return of the node**

```
until echo "SELECT * FROM system.peers LIMIT 1;" | cqlsh `hostname` > /dev/null 2>&1; do echo "Node is still DOWN"; sleep 10; done && echo "Node is now UP"
```

**Confirm that the restarted node has rejoined the cluster**

Tail the /var/log/cassandra/system.log file from one or more other nodes, looking for the following messages:

```
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/192.168.187.124] 2019-12-12 19:17:33,654 OutboundTcpConnection.java:485 - Handshaking version with /192.168.187.124
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2019-12-12 19:18:23,212 Gossiper.java:1019 - Node /192.168.187.124 is now part of the cluster
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2019-12-12 19:18:23,213 Gossiper.java:984 - InetAddress /192.168.187.124 is now UP
```

**Confirm that the expected number of nodes is in the cluster**

The result of the following command should be identical across all nodes:

```
nodetool status
```